# Embark colorscheme not working properly

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I have installed embark using vim-plug. I have put it inside my vimrc. But everytime I open vim, it shows this error

```
Error detected while processing /home/pial/.vim/vimrc:
line    9:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'embark'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But, when I am inside vim, and then use the command mode to select embark as my colorscheme, then it works.

My .vimrc file:

```
autocmd! bufwritepost vimrc ++nested source %


" change leader key to <space>, previously it was <alt>
let mapleader = " "


" colorscheme
colorscheme embark

" setting linenumbers and relative line numbers
set nu rnu

" incremental searching for vim
set incsearch

" shows command in the status bar
set showcmd

" Plugins installed using vim-plug
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'embark-theme/vim', { 'as': 'embark' }

call plug#end()
```

I am using VIm 8.1 and my OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reorder the commands in your vimrc, to only set the colorscheme after the `plug#end()` call.

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'embark-theme/vim', { 'as': 'embark' }
call plug#end()

colorscheme embark
```

The reason why this is important is that `plug#end()` is what will modify the `'runtimepath'` setting, which is what allows Vim to find plug-in files in directories where those plug-ins reside. Since the colorscheme is coming from a plug-in managed by vim-plug, you need that to be set up first, before it's actually available.

Comment: It works fine now. Thanks.